# Can't make chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'll add a chart to my site, but if I do that, I've nothing from result. I use ChartJS as external library.

Here is my code:

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random()*100)
};

var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]
}

window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/src/Chart.Bar.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<div style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

and a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb2opyd8/2/)

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qb2opyd8/3/

What I´ve done:

- Used `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js`
- Changed the JS Fiddle config to `No wrap - in <body>`